"Error installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.8 in .NET Framework 4.7.2 project"
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.8'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
i tried to install package but its throwing an error
